# by 3d dxf to shp with field height

Tags: shapefile, 3d, dxf, tin

I have a question
from a DXF file " topographic precision 3 cm " with 3d polylines to get one shp line with information 3d is possible?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using a DXF to CSV converter which gave me points with XYZ which I was able to build tins from in paraview or interpolate from in QGIS